# Flutter problem with interaction of fields

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I interact with any field, it automatically gives me an error to enter a valid email, but it should notify me when entering an invalid email address. I've tried everything, but the problem persists. I'm a beginner with Flutter, so this is causing me trouble. The code is attached:

```
import 'package:bubble_v1/UI/register_login_page/button_rl.dart';
import 'package:bubble_v1/UI/register_login_page/fields/email_field.dart';
import 'package:bubble_v1/UI/register_login_page/login_page.dart';
import 'package:bubble_v1/UI/register_login_page/fields/password_field.dart';
import 'package:bubble_v1/UI/register_login_page/fields/text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  final lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  bool _confirmPasswordVisible = false;
  bool _isRegisterButtonEnabled = false;

  // Toggle password visibility
  void _togglePasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
    });
  }

  void _toggleConfirmPasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _confirmPasswordVisible = !_confirmPasswordVisible;
    });
  }

  // Validate all fields and update button state
  void _updateRegisterButtonState() {
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if (formState == null) return; // Handle null state

    setState(() {
      _isRegisterButtonEnabled = formState.validate() && passwordController.text.isNotEmpty && confirmPasswordController.text.isNotEmpty && passwordController.text == confirmPasswordController.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firstnameController.addListener(_updateRegisterButtonState);
    lastnameController.addListener(_updateRegisterButtonState);
    emailController.addListener(_updateRegisterButtonState);
    passwordController.addListener(_updateRegisterButtonState);
    confirmPasswordController.addListener(_updateRegisterButtonState);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    firstnameController.dispose();
    lastnameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    confirmPasswordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
              onChanged: _updateRegisterButtonState,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // free space 50
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),

                  // Logo
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 100,
                  ),

                  // free space 40
                  const SizedBox(height: 40),

                  // First Name
                  MyTextFieldRL(
                    controller: firstnameController,
                    hintText: 'First Name',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),

                  // free space 20
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Last Name
                  MyTextFieldRL(
                    controller: lastnameController,
                    hintText: 'Last Name',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),

                  // free space 20
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Email
                  EmailField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                  ),

                  // free space 20
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Password
                  PasswordField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    obsecureText: !_passwordVisible,
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(_passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                      onPressed: _togglePasswordVisibility,
                    ),
                  ),

                  // free space 20
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Confirm Password
                  PasswordField(
                    controller: confirmPasswordController,
                    hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                    obsecureText: !_confirmPasswordVisible,
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(_confirmPasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: _toggleConfirmPasswordVisibility,
                    ),
                  ),

                  // free space 50
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),

                  // Register Button
                  Opacity(
                    opacity: _isRegisterButtonEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.5,
                    child: MyButtonRL(
                      onTap: _isRegisterButtonEnabled
                          ? () {
                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                print('Register button pressed and form is valid');
                              }
                            }
                          : null,
                      hintText: 'Register',
                    ),
                  ),

                  // free space 50
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),

                  // Down line
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Divider(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            thickness: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            'Already have an account?',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Divider(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            thickness: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  // free space 20
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Login Button
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                              pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const LoginPage(),
                              transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EmailField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final Icon prefixIcon;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;

  const EmailField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.prefixIcon,
    this.validator,
  });

  String? emailValidator(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {}

    String pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+';
    RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value!)) {
      return 'Please make sure your email address is valid';
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 15),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true,
          hintText: hintText,
          prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
        ),
        validator: validator ?? emailValidator,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried various variations and modifications in both files, but nothing has worked so far. I can't seem to find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You get validation errors immediately because you call `formState.validate()` every time a value of your fields changes (thanks to calling `_updateRegisterButtonState` in each field's controller.

You might want to check for the fields' validity without calling `validate()` if you don't want the validation to show errors, instead you can get email field value through `emailController.text` and pass it to your validation method.